# update-grub does not update /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, 18.04

(EDIT 3: User error. Copied over /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg while debugging a boot problem)

After installing recently released Ubuntu 18.04 Server in UEFI Secure Boot mode the installer has put grub.cfg in this location:

- **/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg**

This matches the tables created when selecting Filesystem: manual partition, which mounts the boot partion at **/boot/efi** (/dev/sda1).

However, **sudo update-grub** and **sudo update-grub2** does not overwrite the grub configuration, instead updating **/boot/grub/grub.cfg**, i.e. a file not on the boot partition.

Question 1: Has update-grub, update-grub2 etc been superseded by some new procedure?
Question 2: If not, is this a bug to be filed?

EDIT:
Confused++.

- Computer 1, actual hardware, manual portioning in installation and minor updates, e.g. **sudo apt install tboot**,  problem **can** be reproduced.
- Computer 2, vmware image: vanilla install, problem **cannot** be reproduced.

Both computers are UEFI Secure Boot and have same/similar partioning. the different grub.cfg experience the same update behaviour, but on the vmware image, grub respects the file **/boot/grub/grub.cfg**, on hardware install grub respects the **/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg**.

EDIT 2:

- Computer 1 has now been re-installed both with manual filesystem portioning and then again with the original partitioning (250GB disk, 120GB used, rest left free). **Neither** re-install could reproduce the original problem, so basically now the problem is gone. All three installations on the computer was from the same ISO / USB stick.

Comment: The sudo update-grub only updates the grub.cfg in /boot whether partition or folder inside / (root). But with UEFI there is another grub.cfg inside the /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu folder. It is just 3 lines and is a configfile entry to find the full grub.cfg in your install. I have multiple Ubuntu installs, and each new install overwrites the ESP and my main working grub.cfg. I learned to back up ESP, particularly the grub.cfg to restore main working install as default boot.

Comment: thanks oldfred. explanation was very simple: user error. I copied over /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg while trying to debug why some settings didn't take effect, and from that point on behaviour was non-standard on my system.

Comment: Next time try just creating the grub directory under boot: `$> sudo mkdir -p /boot/grub`. For some reason, grub-mkconfig doesn't automatically create the grub directory in boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

root cause: user error.

I accidentally copied /boot/grub/grub.cfg to /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg while trying to debug some grub settings didn't take effect. From that point on behaviour was non-standard on my system.

thanks to oldfred for helping me realise the original /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg had just been a three lines file referring /boot/grub.cfg.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this as well.  To update your EFI grub.cfg, you want to do:

```
grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi
```

If your EFI is mounted at `/boot/efi`.

Comment: Worked for me on Mint 20 (Ubuntu 20.04) but have to use `sudo` otherwise get misleading errors.

Answer (score 10):

Just to close the loop on this query - I needed updates to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` because I had changed the location of my `/boot` directory (UUID changed).  `update-grub` doesn't update that file, but

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-efi-amd64
```

will trigger a re-write, after you have answered some questions.

Comment: quite likely this depends on how you installed - on newer machines/installs there are other variants of this package that might be more appropriate - eg `grub-efi-amd64-signed`.  check with `dpkg -l "*grub-efi*"`

Answer (score 3):

blaufish notes that

> the original /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg had just been a three lines file referring /boot/grub.cfg.

This three line grub.cfg is **not used**, at least on my grub 2.02-2ubuntu8.6 with btrfs.  The 2nd line reads

```
set prefix=($root)'/@/boot/grub'
```

There is now no @ on $root, and there wasn't when grub-install was run.  (@ was a zesty install that became corrupt, and deleted some time ago.)   Instead, the grub path to grub.cfg is written into the grubx64.efi executable.  One might see what this is by running

```
strings grubx64.efi | tail
```

I mention this because somebody might imagine, as I did once, that changing this grub.cfg to point somewhere else would be useful.  I use the --boot-directory option to grub-install to set this.  I have the btrfs root mounted (subvolid=5,subvol=/) at /mnt/top, and want to boot to /@grub:

> --boot-directory=/mnt/top/@grub/boot

(I'm not sure this has always worked.  When I first tried to set up grub independently of any install on btrfs, I had trouble, and ended up using a snapshot that I could boot from to make grub-install write what I wanted.  But it's good now.)

Answer (score 0):

I changed /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg using vi. There you need change only UID and gpt. Works fine. Be carefull.

Answer (score 0):

Please `apt remove grub-pc` and make sure `grub-efi-amd64` is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Using UEFI and full disk encryption (FDE) the grub config below `/boot/grub/` is residing on encrypted media. As such being accessible not until after booting from GRUB and unlocking it.

Therefore a working grub config outside `/boot/grub` is required. This is what the ESP with its `EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` (mounted on `/boot/efi`) is used for.

To keep both grub.cfg files in sync, you can use the following method:

```
dpkg-divert --divert /usr/sbin/update-grub.orig --rename /usr/sbin/update-grub
update-alternatives --install /usr/sbin/update-grub update-grub /usr/local/sbin/update-grub 100
```

This is creating a diversion for `/usr/sbin/update-grub`, meaning packages updating `/usr/sbin/update-grub` will be diverted to `/usr/sbin/update-grub.orig`. Effectively preventing any interference of system updates with this local modification, i.e. updating grub packages will respect the diversion and modify `/usr/sbin/update-grub.orig` only.

The second step is installing an alternative for `/usr/sbin/update-grub` pointing to the locally modified file in `/usr/local/sbin/update-grub`

Lastly, create `/usr/local/sbin/update-grub` as:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
echo "$0: Updating grub BIOS config.";
/usr/sbin/update-grub.orig "$@"

echo "$0: Updating grub UEFI config.";
exec grub-mkconfig  --output=/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg "$@"
```

This is first updating the BIOS config via `update-grub.orig` and then updating the real deal, the UEFI config. This way, both config files are kept in sync all the while being transparent to system updates and package management.